# access date format in query not working merged fields

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have two fields, stopdate and stoptime.  I put together a query to merge these as one field.  It looks valid, 01/02/2015 14:09:30, BUT, when I try to use this field (sort, filter criteria, ect) it is clear that it is being looked at as a text field.  ive tried  ([Stop Date]+[Stop Time]) AS Stopdatetime, as well as using the format function.   I tried using Format([Stopdatetime],"mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss") AS Date1 in my select statement.

Before anyone throws out "helpful tips", no, i cant change the regional settings, no, i cant force the users to store it as one field, and no, i cant create a new field to store the data.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about getting them as a date. Something like this when you are merging them:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, 0, DATEDIFF(day, 0, your_date_column)) +
    DATEADD(day, 0 - DATEDIFF(day, 0, your_time_column), your_time_column)
FROM your_table
```

or you can also try something like this:

```
DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, '00:00:00', [Time]), CONVERT(DATETIME, [Date]))
```

**EDIT** Notice you tagged  ms-access-2010. Those should work for SQL Server 2008 and after but not sure for MS Access

Comment: @DanaJ that is fine, basically you are creating another date field. That should work with MSSQL but not sure for MS Access tho

Comment: Stopdatetime: DateAdd("s",DateDiff("s",0,[Stop Time]),[Stop Date]) worked in access

Answer (score 0):

This is *way* simpler to achieve than you expect:

```
Select [Stop Date] + [Stop Time] As [StopDateTime]
From YourTable
```

If fields are not of data type Date, convert these:

```
Select DateValue([Stop Date]) + TimeValue([Stop Time]) As [StopDateTime]
From YourTable
```

Comment: Did you bother to read my post?  i said" ive tried ([Stop Date]+[Stop Time]) AS Stopdatetime,".  What happens with that is that i get something that is formatted as a date, but sorts as text.

Comment: Then your fields are not of data type Datetime. If so, `[Stop Date]+[Stop Time]` _will_ return a date value which can be sorted on as any other Date field. There is no way that expression can result in a Text value. If they are text, convert them - see edited answer, please.

Comment: Except they are datetime fields, and they are not returning a date, so there must be some kind of way that it happens :/

Comment: The only other result would be _Null_ if one (or both) fields are _Null_. It is plain impossible to have the expression to return a string.